# Different headheight in odd or even pages with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

With the `fancyhdr` package I would like to set different `headheight` in odd and even pages, do I tried with

```
\setlength{\headheight}{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{.5cm}{3cm}}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: what about   textheight?

Comment: doesn't work better

Comment: Your text has to begin at the same height on the physical page, I suppose?

Comment: what i mean is that the body text will be pushed down in odd pages so you need to change the text height (this is same as what Bernard points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}

%--- just for the example
\textheight=20\baselineskip
\markboth{My headings}{Bla bla}
\usepackage{mwe}
%---

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\headheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 0.5cm\else 3cm\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

What i think better: change textheight too

```
\documentclass{book}

%--- just for the example
\textheight=20\baselineskip
\markboth{My headings}{Bla bla}
\usepackage{mwe}
%---

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\headheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 0.5cm\else 3cm\fi}{}{}
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\global\@colht\textheight}{\global\advance\textheight by\ifodd\count\z@ -2.5cm\else 2.5cm\fi\global\@colht\textheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one can change `\topmargin` to avoid changing  `\textheight`