# Different top and bottom margins for odd or even pages

Tags: margins, geometry, double-sided, landscape

I have a two-sided landscape document that I intend to bind on the long (top/bottom) edge. To leave space for the binding, I would like a larger top margin on odd-numbered pages and a larger bottom margin on even-numbered pages. How should I do this?

I can set the margins to be the same for every page with

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, landscape]{geometry}
```

but adding a binding offset with

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bindingoffset=1cm, landscape]{geometry}
```

adds the extra space onto the left (odd) and right (even) margins, rather what I want: the top (odd) and bottom (even) margins.

Comment: May be you can have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332248/different-headheight-in-odd-or-even-pages-with-fancyhdr/332272#332272