# inner/outer equivalent for top/bottom in landscape, two-sided document

Tags: geometry, double-sided, landscape

I want to create a document in landscape and bind it on the long side, therefore I want to use different margins for top and bottom margins on odd/even pages, but I only found the `inner` and `outer` parameters for the left and right margins. Is there an equivalent for top and bottom margins or another way to solve it.

I found this answer: [Different headheight in odd or even pages with fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332248/different-headheight-in-odd-or-even-pages-with-fancyhdr), but it only deals with `headheight` but not with the margin at the bottom.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{inner = 25mm, outer = 5mm} % this but for top and bottom and reversed for even/odd pages

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can try `\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{\global\addtolength{\topmargin}{\ifodd\value{page}-\fi2cm}}`

Comment: waiting for an answer in July 2022.